# Error installing AutoitLibrary through command line

Tags: command-line, pip, robotframework, autoit

I need to install robotframework-autoitlibrary to use on my test cases. 
My problem is when I try to install AutoIt Library through command line with the following command:

```
pip install -U robotframework-autoitlibrary --no-cache-dir --pre
```

I have this error:

```
  C:\windows\system32>pip install -U robotframework-autoitlibrary --no-cache- 
    dir --pre
    Collecting robotframework-autoitlibrary
    Downloading 
 https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/a4/9e51fe35b1da7a006b773c9c234f78e89bcc4f267152c4e9fa8260631fa8/robotframework-autoitlibrary-1.2.2.zip (701kB)
    100% |################################| 706kB 1.6MB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\user-a~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install- 
    oro1ov\robotframework-autoitlibrary\setup.py", line 93, in <module>
        destPath = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.getenv("HOMEDRIVE"), 
    r"\RobotFramework\Extensions\AutoItLibrary"))
      File "c:\python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 65, in join
        result_drive, result_path = splitdrive(path)
      File "c:\python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 115, in splitdrive
        if len(p) > 1:
    TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
    c:\users\user-a~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-oro1ov\robotframework- 
    autoitlibrary\
```

My currently installed python packages and their versions are:

```
Pillow==5.3.0
Pygments==2.3.1
pypiwin32==223
Pypubsub==4.0.0
pywin32==224
robotframework==3.1
robotframework-ride==1.5.2.1
robotframework-selenium2library==3.0.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.3.0
selenium==3.141.0
six==1.12.0
typing==3.6.6
urllib3==1.24.1
wxPython==4.0.3
```

I already try this command:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

When input echo %HOMEDRIVE%, the output is:

```
C:\Users\cmpeixoto>echo %HOMEDRIVE%
C:
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Please post the complete error trace.

Comment: Before jumping into premature answers, can you address this - is your computer in an AD (active directory)? What is the output of this shell command - `echo %HOMEDRIVE%` - when you run it in the **same** Command Prompt session as the failing pip install?

Comment: @todor My computer isn't in an AD. The output of thal shell command is placed above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error looks like the environment variable `HOMEDRIVE` is not set, even though it has a value according to your test (the library installer uses it to copy some files).

Can you try this - manually set it, and straight after that run the `pip` - in the same Command Prompt (cmd) session:

```
set HOMEDRIVE=C:
pip install -U robotframework-autoitlibrary --no-cache-dir --pre
```

Comment: Glad it did; strange it didn't work out of the box, the variable is usually set, it's one of Windows rudimentary ones. If this didn't work, I would've asked you to open cmd in elevated privileges ("run as administrator") - note to anyone else that may end up here with this problem in the future. And if that didn't work, I'd be hands off :) (the final-final solution would be manual install/editing the installer to skip that copy step - a bit too much for SO :)